# Upgrading the nuget package issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have 2 Packages in Visual Studio 
1) System.Web.Http.OData (Version 5.3.1)
2) Microsoft.Data.Odata (Version 5.6.0)

When I tried to upgrade the Microsoft.Data.OData package to version 5.8.4(and all its dependencies like System.Spatial and Microsoft.Data.Edm to 5.8.4)

Then When Executing the code the package System.Web.Http.OData is still trying to use the 5.6 version of Microsoft.Data.Odata and not the 5.8.4 and getting couldn't find assembly.. error

```
System.Web.Http.OData.ODataFormattingAttribute.Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
```

So how can change the version of Microsoft.Data.Odata in System.Web.Http.OData so that it can point to new version?